# What are the differences between on-off control, proportional only control, and fuzzy control?

Tags: control, control-system, terminology

How we can differentiate between these 3 concepts: On-off control and proportional only (where integral and derivative gains are zero) control and fuzzy control?

I am especially confused in the difference between the last two concepts, proportional only control and fuzzy control as on-off control has only two values 0 and 100% but proportional and fuzzy can have any value between 0 and 100 and so apparently they both look almost similar.

How is proportional control different from fuzzy logic in mathematical/equation terms and also from the point of view of application/use?

Comment: Please clarify the question. There are many differences. Depending on the application, these can be pros/cons. What is the purpose?

Comment: Look at how the output is calculated. Proportional is a simple equation, fuzzy is somewhat different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps an illustrated example would do.

Also, given that my understanding of the "fuzzy" concept might, itself, be faulty.  Think I last read much about it years ago, and found it a lot of words for not saying much (and understanding even less of that).  So, this is based on what definition or understanding I've internalized, not formally based on academic sources.

A typical SMPS uses a "fuzzy" mechanism: at nominal to full load, it operates proportionally.  At light load, the control is turned off periodically, perhaps as a hysteretic control.  This actually goes into the on-off control mode, but it indeed illustrates a transition between proportional and digital modes.

The transition between these modes can be as seamless as using the same process variable (i.e., an integrating error amp's output, i.e. an SMPS controller's `COMP` node/pin) and putting some thresholds on it.  At the top of the range, we might apply some maximum limiting function, or fade into another function like current or temperature or other limiting (or, well, more likely those are always ready to take over, but just happen to themselves be in the background, most of the time); and at the low end, we might put a cutoff, below which, operation simply ceases.

Note that, in the proportional mode, the error amp's output varies smoothly with load response, as expected; at light load, its output still varies continuously up and down, but it's forced to ping-pong over a range due to that hard threshold; well, that and either system phase shift, hysteresis, or both -- note that a zero-phase loop would ping-pong ~instantaneously, so we want to enforce some kind of maximum on-off period to enforce the intention: i.e., burst mode operation to reduce switching losses, etc.).

---

Another application I'm fond of, is using the LM3914 bargraph display driver IC as a unary ADC (which, really, is an excellent description of what it is).

By unary, I mean that the output is in terms of the number of active outputs.  Which is precisely what a bargraph display is, after all.  Contrast this with a positional system like binary, where each output carries twice the numerical weight of the last: which, to be fair, you could display on a bargraph too, but you have to be able to see the pattern and positions to actually read it: that's not a *bar graph!*

Well, say we use such an ADC to drive a row of switched (identical) resistors, which therefore sink current from a load, in proportion to the applied voltage and number of active bits.  Further suppose we set the ADC's reference voltage proportional to load voltage: now the number of active resistors decreases with increasing output voltage: in fact, inversely so.  That means we get an average *constant-current characteristic*, despite using an entirely digital implementation!

The 10 bits* from the LM3914 aren't exactly fine-grained, though.  In fact they're rather gross.  We could use such a system as an electronically controlled load, but we'd still need a continuous (analog) current sink to smooth out the gaps.  But the interesting thing is, those gaps are much smaller than if the analog sink had to do all the work by itself -- such a scheme potentially saves the cost of several transistors, and related heatsinking hardware and etc., trading it for a bit of clever circuitry and a pile of resistors (which can run hotter than the transistors, potentially making a smaller build too).

*Bits are binary though; units, I guess?

Under the lens of fuzzy logic, such a system is like a two-digit number, but the first digit is not a, well, digit, but a continuum, an analog variable.  For numbers 00 through 09, the digital-digit remains 0, but the analog-digit varies smoothly from 0 to 9 (or, 9.999.. let's say).  The instant the analog-digit overflows to [what would be] 10, the digital bit is incremented instead, and the analog digit wraps around to 0.  And so on from 10 to 19, 20 to 29, etc.

The catch of an implementation like this, is the analog variable follows a ramp -- a discontinuous wave, ideally speaking, but real signals are never discontinuous, so there will always be some discrepancy as the system switches from one (digital) state to the next.  For the imagined electronic load, this means some amount of output noise (due to quantization); it wouldn't be a good solution for low-noise purposes.

---

Finally, contrast with a fully digital control.  We can implement ""continuum"" variables by using integers of arbitrarily long bit size.  This works quite well in practice: CD wave audio achieves near human aural perfection with a mere 16 bits; real signals beyond about 30 bits are, at best, terrifically difficult to measure with any repeatability.  Meanwhile, modern CPUs effortlessly operate on whopping 64 bit words.

Note that "fully digital" generally means quantized value AND time; it is a DSP system (living in the Z-transform domain, plus quantization noise).  The time quantization (read: all outputs synchronized to a master clock) isn't a necessity, but it is much easier to design and build digital systems employing that paradigm (and it is obligatory when using pre-cooked digital systems like MCUs).

---

So, in summary, a fuzzy system combines digital and analog aspects; it may be as simple as adding thresholds or limits, or have multiple states, whether related to a (continuous) input, or an internal continuum state, or internal digital state (as something like a

I suppose you could argue everything is fuzzy, as, at the very least, pure proportional behavior is a strict subset of fuzzy logic (i.e., the digital aspect uses zero or more bits, inclusive); and real "proportional" systems necessarily have a limit, beyond which something else must happen (whether it be simply running out of available output voltage, or anything up to exploding..).  So, I never really thought much of it, personally, or found it all that illustrative, and it always seemed gimmicky.

Perhaps its power is more humble, subtle, only relevant at a higher level, hard to appreciate from a basic description: it is a way to enumerate all possible states of a system, and therefore draw a finite state diagram, despite some of those states being indefinite continua.  We don't have to consider every possible (digital) state combined with every possible (analog) transfer function or differential equation, only the specific pairs that are allowed by the design.

Comment: Thanka alot for your courteous & detailed response. So in nutshell you mean , fuzzy logic can have values in decimal points but proportional will have purely discrete value(will not have decimal point value)??

Comment: Fuzzy has both. Proportional has purely continuous. Digital has purely discrete.

Comment: Do You mean that Fuzzy has both digital and analog(continous) aspects but proportional only has analog(continous)aspects??